# Smoothness along rays sufficient for global smoothness

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hi,

Suppose I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ and I know that $f$ is smooth ($C^\infty$) along each ray $t \mapsto f(td)$ on $t \in [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ and all directions $d \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Is smoothness along these rays sufficient for $f$ to be smooth around $0$ as a multivariate function (all partial derivatives exist)?

Thanks.

Comment: No.  Just take a non-smooth function $g \colon S^{d-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(-p) = -g(p)$ and define $f(v) = \|v\|g(v/\|v\|)$.  This is smooth since on each ray it is just $t \mapsto k t$ for some $k$, but the non-smoothness of $g$ means that $f$ is not smooth.  The closest to this that I know of is if you take all smooth curves (not just rays).  Then $f$ is smooth.  This is due to Jan Boman.

Comment: That is indeed a nice counterexample. 

Would you happen to have a reference of this result of Jan Boman? In addition, would smoothness along all real analytic curves be sufficient too?

Comment: The result Andrew Stacey refers to is this paper of Boman (MathSciNet link): http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=237728 The article doesn't look like it is available online. In the MathSciNet review the following counterexample is mentioned: there exists a non-continuous function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\circ u \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ for every quasianalytic $u$. (Though it is not clear which quasianalytic class the example applies to.) This should give at least a partial answer to your follow-up question. 

Comment: Thanks Willie.

Looking at the Boman paper, demanding smoothness along only analytic curves is indeed not sufficient. 

It turns out that when $f \circ u$ is real analytic for every real analytic curve $u$, that $f$ is real analytic. See "An Ontology of Directional Regularity Implying Joint Regularity" published in Real Analysis Exchange, available at http://www.math.wustl.edu/~sk/joint.pdf .


Comment: Apparently, in the published version there is the condition that the k-th partial derivative of $f \circ u$ needs to be smaller than $C k! / r^k$ for some $r>0$.

Comment: The main proof of Boman's theorem is contained in one of the early sections of Kriegl and Michor's book _A Convenient Setting for Global Analysis_ which *is* available for free online from the AMS bookstore.  They also look at analytic and holomorphic versions (can't remember who these are due to off the top of my head).  There's also a version for functions with $k$ derivatives and a Lipschitz condition on the last one.